# CQ5 - How to get rendered JSP path or file name

Tags: jsp, path, adobe, render, aem

"Test" Page is using a CQ page component called "myComponent". myComponent has more than 2 different JSP files to be rendered. I want to use and write in to the JSP output the path or file name of the rendered JSP for every request.
At this point I can get the currentPage, node and component paths (/content/test, /content/test/jcr:content, /apps/application/components/page/newComponent) but I cant make it to get the rendered JSP path.
Does anyone know how to get information from the actual rendered JSP? Thanks guys

Comment: I have not found a good way to do this.  If all you need to do is trace files for debugging purposes, you could include an HTML comment in each of your source .jsp files with the file's name or other identifier in the comment.  For instance, if you use SVN, you could code <!-- $Id --> in each file.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<%= resource.getPath() %>`

Comment: This will return the same result for any resolution script, so will not be able to determinate which one is resolving the request.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CQ5.4+ then you can use a SlingRequestProcessor to allow CQ to call itself to gather the rendered output for a page.  This blog entry has some further details:

http://cqdump.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/cq5-requesting-itself/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your problem but you can do something like:

```
currentPage.getPath();
```

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help, as it returns the path of the component, not the path of the rendering script

Comment: Are you looking for the template?, you can try currentPage.getTemplate() that would give you information on the template being used to create the page.